# Unable To Register a Background task Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-8.1

I Need To Run Some Functions In Background In My Windows Phone 8.1 App.
I Have Created A Different Project For Background Tasks In My Solutions.
But Application Is Crashing When I Try To Register Following BG Task.
Here is My Code To Register Task`

```
    private async void TasksRegistration()
    {
        var taskRegistered = false;
        var TaskName = "FirstBG";

        // Checking If Task Is Already Registered..
        foreach (var task in Windows.ApplicationModel.Background.BackgroundTaskRegistration.AllTasks)
        {
            if (task.Value.Name == exampleTaskName)
            {
                taskRegistered = true;
                return;
            }
        }

        var builder = new BackgroundTaskBuilder();

        builder.Name = TaskName;
        builder.TaskEntryPoint = "BackGroundTask.FirstBG";
        builder.SetTrigger(new TimeTrigger(15, true));
        await BackgroundExecutionManager.RequestAccessAsync();
        BackgroundTaskRegistration Task = builder.Register();
    }
```

Application Crashed On Last Line When I Try Register This Task.
I Have Written XML Code In .Appx Manifest.

Comment: What kind of exception is being thrown? Is your BackgroundTask a RuntimeComponent? Have you added suitable declarations in your package?

Comment: Yes For Last Two... I Couldn't Get Exception Details Even With Catch Statement... a File Named App.g.i.cs  Pops up And App Crashes.

Comment: Have you added a reference to RuntimeComponent in your main project?

Comment: Yes..I have referanced to Universal Windows Runtime Component..

Comment: try this http://www.romasz.net/how-to-add-a-backgroundtask/

Comment: Solved.. Wrongly configured package.. sorry for trouble.. I have one more question can we have a trigger for task .. so task will launch once daily.. lets say Every Midnight..

Comment: I don't understand last question - you are setting a trigger in your code - 15 minutes, try to set it to few hours - it should work. Remember only that BTasks have some constraints dependant on their type.

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem, it is most likely do to the fact that your Background Task Project is not set as a Windows Runtime Component.

Make sure the Output Type: is set to a Windows Runtime Component

[image]